# How to Remember the position of RecyclerVIew Items after Drag and Drop

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, itemtouchhelper

I have recyclerVIew in which  I implement ItmeTouchHelper to drag and drop the items of RecyclerVIew but the positions of items are not saved

```
var itemTouch = ItemTouchHelper(object : 

    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,0){
                override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, source: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?): Boolean {
                    var source = source?.adapterPosition
                    var target = target?.adapterPosition
                    Collections.swap(database.DairyData(),source!!,target!!)
                    adapter.notifyItemMoved(source,target)
                    return true

                }

                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, direction: Int) {

                }

            })
                    itemTouch.attachToRecyclerView(Dairy_recyclerView)
```

Comment: I found your question little unclear, what do you mean by " positions of items are not saved"?

Comment: Means if I drag and drop items of recyclerView and close the applications the items restore back to its original position , I want to keeep the items at place where I dropped

Comment: Where do you retrieve the data from for the recyclerview? To make those changes persistent, you need to ... well... persist them. You can use local sqlite db, a file, or a network repository (eg. firebase)